# {django-tables} Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'name' is not defined

Tags: python, django

Please why am I get the following error:

```
Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'name' is not defined.
```

Initially I did not receive this sort of error, it just surfaced all
off a sudden. I restored my app to the state where everything worked
and I'm still getting the same error.

Full stack trace:

```
Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'name' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://site/reports
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'name' is not defined
Exception Location:     build\bdist.win32\egg\django_tables\models.py in
_default_render, line 73
Python Executable:      C:\path\apache\apache2.2.10\bin\httpd.exe
Python Version: 2.7.1
```

Further details in the template trace back

```
Template error

In template c:\path\to\project\templates\webapp\reports.html, error at line 41
Caught NameError while rendering: global name 'name' is not defined

31                              {% for column in table.columns %}
32                              <th {% if forloop.first %} class="first" {% endif %} {% if forloop.last %} class="last" {% endif %} class="table-header">
33                                  {% if column.sortable %}
34                                    <a href="?sort={{ column.name_toggled }}">
35                                      {{ column }}  
36                                    </a>
37                                  {% endif %}
38                              </th>
39                              {% endfor %}
40                          </tr>
41                          {% for row in table.rows %}
42                            <tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}">
43                            {% for value in row %}
44                              <td class="table-data">{{ value }}<td>
45                            {% endfor %}
46                            </tr>
47                          {% endfor %}
48                          </tbody>
49                      </table>
50                      <div class="actions-bar wat-cf">
51

                        <div class="actions">
```

In my template file:

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load tables %}
{% load pagination_tags %}
{% autopaginate rows 2 %}
{% for row in table.rows %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}">
{% for value in row %}
<td class="table-data">{{ value }}<td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

When i remove the above code from my template the error goes away but
table rows are not displayed.

### code from views.py

```
class TransactionReport(tables.ModelTable):
    identifier = tables.Column(sortable=False, visible=False)
    created = tables.Column(sortable=True, visible=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_reports_paid(self, object, req):
        return TransactionReport(object, order_by=req)

    class Meta:  
        model = Transaction


    @login_required
    def display_reports(request):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        dataqs = Transaction.objects.filter(paid="TRUE")
        req = request.GET.get('sort', 'created')
        tx = TransactionReport().get_reports_paid(dataqs, req)

        return render_to_response('webapp/reports.html', {'table': tx, 'rows' : tx.rows})
```

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the code from build\bdist.win32\egg\django_tables\models.py in
_default_render around line 73

Comment: @Andrew It's probably a `getattr` or something. @drecute do you have any variables, classes, attributes or functions named name in your app?

Comment: @Andrew That reference points to django-tables models.py which is here: https://github.com/dgelvin/django-tables/blob/master/django_tables/models.py. I have edited the error above which points to line 41 of report.html which is `{% for row in table.rows %}`. When i remove that block of code, the error goes away.

Comment: You have `{{ column.name_toggled }}` so that must be the problem... does one of your `column`s not have a `name`?

Comment: I added a new column to the model i'm running Queryset on as well as making a django-tables instance of. Though the column is empty, I don't know if this might be a problem. Again, I have made new edits to the post which includes code from views.py.

Comment: The column I'm running QuerySet on doesn't have a `name`, but it has a ForeignKey on a table which has a column named `name`. Could this be it. As a note, this wasn't as issue earlier on when it worked.

Comment: @Ignacio What are you trying to say?

Comment: just in case you haven't thought about it: if you get stuck with this move to django_tables2 :)