# I want to pass values are gotten in views.py to forms.py

Tags: python, django

I want to pass values are gotten in `views.py` to `forms.py.`
I wrote in `views.py`,

```
def app(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']
```

in forms.py

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

def logic(self):
   #I want to use views.py’s name&age’s value here
```

I am new to Django, so how should I write codes to do my ideal thing?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723465/django-form-passing-parameter-from-view-py-to-forms-gives-out-error

Comment: @MaëlPedretti I read the QA,but I cannot understand how I should write a code...

Comment: What's your python level? You simply have to make two attributes in your form class and set them after `form.is_valid()`

Comment: @MaëlPedretti I am little bit begginer.Would you write codes of your comment in Answer?I cannot catch your comment clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

Use variables in Form class.

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_data = ""
    age = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    age_date = 0

    def logic(self):
        # I want to use views.py’s name&age’s value here
        # You can play here with your age_data and name_data
```

And views.py:

```
def app(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = InputForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.name_data = form.cleaned_data['name']
        age.name_data = form.cleaned_data['age']
```

### EDIT ( I needed a coffee, sorry.. )

I have just seen that your `cleaned_data` come from your form so why not working in it directly like this in form Class:

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def logic(self):
        # I want to use views.py’s name&age’s value here
        # Why don't you use cleaned_data['name'] and age from here?
        name = cleaned_data['name']
```

and simply keep your view like this.

```
def app(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    form = InputForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        age = form.cleaned_data['age']
```

---

## Not sure this will work at 100% procent

but the goal of this answer is not to give you the exact solution but to let you experiment with your problem a bit. As a Python beginer you will learn more if you try by yourself and make a few reasearches.

Also consider reading this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django

Comment: thank you for your answer!!In Edit,how can I use cleaned_data['name'] and age in logic method?I cannot understand clearly in that point...

Comment: Simply by using `cleaned_data['name']` like you would with another variable. Example: `name = cleaned_data['name']`

Answer (score 2):

actually you can access data in a form by `cleaned_data` property (that is a dict object), so as an example checkout `save` method here:

```
class CreatePostFrom(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(required=True)
    des = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=250)
    location = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100)
    tags = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=250)

    def save(self, user):
        tags = self.cleaned_data["tags"].split()
        for tag in tags:
            Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
        post = Post.objects.create(user=user,
                                   image=self.cleaned_data["image"],
                                   des=self.cleaned_data["des"],
                                   location=self.cleaned_data["location"])
        post.tags.add(*tags)
        return post
```